# What is the difference between path.Match and filepath.Match?

Tags: go, glob

The documentation and the code for both seems the same.
Why two duplicate functions?

https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Match

https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not "duplicates", they are part of different packages, so you should examine and interpret them in the *context* of their packages.

Package [`path`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/) *"implements utility routines for manipulating **slash-separated paths**"* **independent** of the platform / operating system.

Package [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) *"implements utility routines for manipulating **filename paths in a way compatible with the target operating system-defined file paths**"*.

So for example `path/filepath` handles the path separator differences between operating systems.

If you look closer to the doc of [`filepath.Match()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match), it ends with:

> On Windows, escaping is disabled. Instead, '\' is treated as path separator.

And there are also term interpretation differences. `path.Match()`:

```
term:
    '*'         matches any sequence of non-/ characters
    '?'         matches any single non-/ character
```

And `filepath.Match()`:

```
term:
    '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
    '?'         matches any single non-Separator character
```

Answer (score 1):

The one in `filepath` package is operating system dependent and the one in `path` package always uses slash (/) as separator.